# Create mhtml file?

Tags: javascript, mhtml

Can any one please suggest, how to create mhtml file using JavaScript?

I have tried to use `Content-Type: 'message/rfc822'`, it downloads mhtml file but when open it in IE there is an empty page.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: used these headers
`From: <Saved by Blink>
                    Snapshot-Content-Location: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/append
                    Subject: Headers.append() - Web APIs | MDN
                    Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2018 09:54:31 -0000
                    MIME-Version: 1.0
                    Content-Type: multipart/related;
                        type="text/html";
                        boundary="----MultipartBoundary--5sRtHLtn7e4WLeVgGR26oU0v4JlNZrwxitQfdTJZh2----"`

Comment: then this function to download file

`function exportFile(fileContent, downloadLinkId) {
        var data = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'message/rfc822' });
        objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        var downloadLinkButton = document.getElementById(downloadLinkId);
        downloadLinkButton.href = objUrl;
    };`

where in content pass my html with upper mentioned headers